# IOS SDK: MapKit - Display two stroke color on MKpolyline

Tags: ios, iphone, mapkit, mkpolyline

I am trying to display two stroke/fill color on single MKPolyline. One color code from Origin to current location and another color from Current location to destination.

In simplest way i can say, i want to show past route on different color code.

How can I do this? Is there any tutorial or sample code?

Thanks

Comment: Simplest approach is to create two MKPolylines with titles "past"/"future" and set strokeColor based on title.

Comment: Is there any way without creating two polylines ? with single polyline?

Comment: You would need to create a custom MKOverlayPathRenderer subclass and do the drawing yourself but then you would also need a custom id<MKOverlay> class which would tell the custom renderer which parts of the line are "past" and "future".  Creating two MKPolylines is much easier.